# Excel JavaScript API (ExcelScript.Workbook), Get row of data with Headers

Tags: javascript, excel, power-automate

New to Excel JS API. Trying to grab a row of data from a table. It must also contain the column headers in the data it returns.

Not seeing a way to do this. Trying to get this to work in the Automate area of an Excel file. So I think it needs to be able to function in this: function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook). Not seeing a way to grab that data with headers.

Ultimately will be firing off from Power Automate. The function needs to be able to get the data and return in stringified JSON format. For example, if I have a table that is "Table2", column headings "Heading1, Heading2, etc" and first row of data is "a,b,c", according to heading (Heading1:a, Heading2:b, etc). How do I grab that row with headers?

I tried using a filter but not sure this is the way to go. Ultimately, I'd like it to be dynamic where you get the table, grab the first row of data (with table headers in the results), and have that data be stringified JSON data that I can do something with.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Get the table in the workbook named "StationTable".
    const table = workbook.getTable("Table2");
    
    // Get the "Station" table column for the filter.
    const stationColumn = table.getColumnByName("Heading1");
    // Apply a filter to the table that will only show rows
    // with a value of "Station-1" in the "Station" column.
    stationColumn.getFilter().applyValuesFilter(["a"]);
    }
```